# How to bind data to two DGVs

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to bind data from Northwind Database (orders) and (order Details) to two datagridviews using a relation in the dataset the form is this:
[image]

The form code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGV_Master_Detail_Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setDataBindings();
        }

        private void setDataBindings()
        {
            DataSet dsTables = new DataSet();
            NorthwndData_ORM northData = new NorthwndData_ORM();
            DataTable dtOrders = northData.getOrders();
            DataTable dtOrderDetails = northData.getOrdersDetails();

            // Adding the tables to the data set
            dsTables.Tables.Add(dtOrders);
            dsTables.Tables.Add(dtOrderDetails);

            // Define relation between tables
            dsTables.Relations.Add("OrderDetailsRelation", dtOrders.Columns["OrderID"], dtOrderDetails.Columns["OrderID"]);

            // Create binding sources for tables
            BindingSource bindOrder = new BindingSource();
            bindOrder.DataSource = dsTables;
            bindOrder.DataMember = "dtOrders";

            BindingSource bindDetails = new BindingSource();
            bindDetails.DataSource = bindOrder;
            bindDetails.DataMember = "OrderDetailsRelation";

            // Bind data to DGVs
            dgvOrders.DataSource = bindOrder;
            dgvOrderDetails.DataSource = bindDetails;



        }

    }
}
```

The data and connection class is:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGV_Master_Detail_Example
{
    class NorthwndData_ORM
    {
        // Table Orders Properties
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShippedDate { get; set; }
        public int ShipVia { get; set; }
        public decimal Freight { get; set; }
        public string ShipName { get; set; }
        public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
        public string ShipCity { get; set; }
        public string ShipRegion { get; set; }
        public string ShipPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ShipCountry { get; set; }

        // Table Order Details Properties
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Discount { get; set; }

        private SqlConnection conn;

        private void connect()
        {
            string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        }

        public DataTable getOrders()
        {
            connect();
            string sqlGetOrders = "SELECT ORD.* FROM dbo.Orders AS ORD";
            DataTable dtOrders = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetOrders, conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sda.Fill(dtOrders);
            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dtOrders;
        }

        public DataTable getOrdersDetails()
        {
            connect();
            string sqlGetOrdersDetails = "SELECT ORDL.* FROM dbo.[Order Details] AS ORDL";
            DataTable dtOrdersDetails = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetOrdersDetails, conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sda.Fill(dtOrdersDetails);
            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dtOrdersDetails;
        }

    }
}
```

The App.Config contents is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conStr"
         connectionString="server=OMEGA-LT\SQLEXPRESS2012; Initial catalog=Northwnd; user id=sa; password=abc123;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The problem is when building and running in debugging mode no error is shown and no data is displayed in either DGVs.
I think I am not using the best binding method!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the dataset should only be used in this case for relational mapping of tables and the data source for binding should be directly linked to the data tables.

Accordingly I have adjusted the code like this:

```
    // Create binding sources for tables
    BindingSource bindOrder = new BindingSource();
    bindOrder.DataSource = dtOrders;

    BindingSource bindDetails = new BindingSource();
    bindDetails.DataSource = bindOrder;
    bindDetails.DataMember = "OrderDetailsRelation";
```

And it works fine, sample run:
[image]